# How to test POST json on playframework controller

Tags: testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

im trying to test POST json to play controller. Controller itself works, I can make a POST using httpie:

```
http --print="HhBb" POST localhost:9000/review some="Its a value"
```

Im trying to test that using:

```
"should post review" in {
  implicit val app = FakeApplication()
  val controller = new ReviewController

  val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/review")
  val home: Future[Result] = route(app, request).get

  contentAsString(home) must be ("asd")

}
```

but I get error in html body:

```
For request 'POST /review' [Host not allowed: ]
```

im play noob, do I have to somehow configure which routes this app use? Ive tried to configure app with GuiceApplicationBuilder since FakeApplication is deprecated, but couldnt make it work either.

Controller:

```
def postReview = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>

  implicit val reviewReads = Json.reads[Review]

  val body = request.body
  println("Json: " + body)

  val review = Json.fromJson[Review](request.body)
  println("Json-body: " + Json.parse(body.toString))

  review match {
    case JsSuccess(r:Review, path: JsPath) => 
      println(s"Review:  $r")
      reviewActor ! review
    case e: JsError => 
      println("Errors: "+ JsError.toJson(e).toString())
  }

  Ok(views.html.index(request.body.toString))
}
```

Comment: The error message "Host not allowed" makes me wonder if you have a `Filter` in your application that may block the mocked request.

Comment: I solve it somehow.. would love to post solution but.. if you dont know framework/language you dont even know what was wrong after couple of refactor phases. I think I did something wrong with play internal router as playframework docs examples shows usage of Router.empty which blow everything, hard to say now.